# Magento 2.2.2 Where did var/generation and var/di go?

Tags: magento2.2, upgrade, magento-2.1.8

I've recently upgraded from 2.1.8 to 2.2.2 CE(Commerce). Seems that `var/di` and `var/generation` are nowhere to be found.

Also did the logic behind the `code generation` changed ? I've noticed some high dependencies on the order of the Child Classes constructor parameters in PHP Dockblock. Above order of parameters in dockblock (/*...*/) making the difference between a successful generation and a failed one.

Comment: Generation should now be in [ROOT]/generated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Magento 2.2 the directories have changed from:

```
var/generation
var/di
```

To

```
generated/code
generated/metadata
```

More info can be found on the dev docs [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html).

Info on how DI compile works can be seen [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html), there are differences between `2.1` and `2.2`. You can switch between versions at the top of the page.